# Error When Installing packages of react js

Tags: reactjs, npm

I've a react js project. When I run `npm i` in vs code show these error.
node-sass version is 4.13.0
npm version is 7.6.3
OS windows 10

error:

```
npm ERR! path D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\programing\\template\\theme\\react\\demo2\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.11.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:200:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:200:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\Mohammad\Anaconda3\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Mohammad\Anaconda3\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                                ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:326:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\programing\\template\\theme\\react\\demo2\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\programing\template\theme\react\demo2\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

How can I solved this problem? Is this the problem of the node-sass version or npm version?

Comment: See [Why is npm install failing with node-sass related errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61853150/2873538)

Comment: You can also downgrade your node version to Node 12 LTS. See [LTS Releases](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass says Node 15 (which evidently you're running) is supported by node-sass version 5.0 upwards.

Try installing that version of node-sass instead.

Comment: I've install latest version of node js and npm version on my OS.

Comment: Yes, but that version of node-sass is not compatible with Node 15. Upgrade to node-sass 5.

Comment: I don't want to update node-sass version in project.

Comment: Then you'll need to downgrade to Node 13. See the link in my post, it has a compatibility table.